# Set auto download preference profile using selenium2library

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

Environment: robotframework-selenium2library

I am looking for a way in selenium2library to make the auto-downloading the file by setting the preference in FirefoxProfile as this is the solution I can find. 
However, it seems that I can not use the way I listed as following in selenium webdriver to import the preference profile into the browser in selenium2library.

Using selenium webdriver: 
`fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()`
`fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)`
`fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)`
`fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir",getcwd())`
`fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/msword, application/csv, application/ris, text/csv, image/png, application/pdf, text/html, text/plain, application/zip, application/x-zip, application/x-zip-compressed, application/download, application/octet-stream")`
`browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)`

I can find the open_browser() in selenium2library but it only eats a directory instead of the flexibility of using the preference profile like selenium webdriver.

Selenium2Library: 
`open_browser(self, url, browser='firefox', alias=None,remote_url=False, desired_capabilities=None,ff_profile_dir=None)`

**Could anyone shed me some light on this if I can do the same way as selenium webdriver in robotframework-selenium2library?**

I found one closed issue talking about this on Github
https://github.com/rtomac/robotframework-selenium2library/issues/18

However, it seems to use profile directory instead of having the flexibility to set the preference for firefox profile.

**Thank you!!**

Comment: It is highly appreciated with any advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> I can find the open_browser() in selenium2library but it only eats a
>   directory

No. It also eats preferences. The long story goes like this:

I am not quite sure how you actually use robotframework-selenium2library. The *common* usage, I would say, is to run robotframework test cases (i.e. simple UTF-8 text files) which import selenium2library. A possible solution to your problem would look like this (it goes without saying that all variables should be defined below `*** Variables ***`):

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Selenium2Library
Library           Collections

*** Variables ***

*** Test Cases ***
MyTestCase
    ${preferences} =    Create Dictionary   browser.download.folderList  2  browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting  False   # and so on ....
    Open Browser    <yourURL>    desired_capabilities=${preferences}
```

However, your question suggests that you intend to directly use python functions (like `open_browser` that you mentioned in your question) provided by selenium2library. In that case, all you need to do is to call that function with parameter `desired_capabilities` set appropriately.

Please note the documentation on that parameter (
full code is to be found [here](https://github.com/rtomac/robotframework-selenium2library/blob/master/src/Selenium2Library/keywords/_browsermanagement.py)):

> If you specify a value for remote you can also specify
>   'desired_capabilities' which is a string in the form
>   key1:val1,key2:val2 that will be used to specify desired_capabilities
>   to the remote server. This is useful for doing things like specify a
>   proxy server for internet explorer or for specify browser and os if
>   your using saucelabs.com. 'desired_capabilities' can also be a
>   dictonary (created with 'Create Dictionary') to allow for more complex
>   configurations.

Comment: Thanks for your more information. I am directly using the library instead of writing the recipe. I got the feedback from the github to know that they do not support profile instance being passed to open_browser() but it seems interesting that you can use recipe to do that.